# Lombok import and @XXX does not work in Java with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, microservices, lombok

Eclipse gives me an error on all things related to Lombok...
I added Lombok in the ordinary way to Eclipse.

But the following `import`-statement

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
```

shows me the error:

```
The import lombok.AllArgsConstructor cannot be resolved
```

For every lombok annotation, say `@AllArgsConstructor` I'm getting the error like

```
AllArgsConstructor cannot be resolved to a type
```

For `@Getter` I'm getting:

```
Getter is not an annotation type
```

I am grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: have you added a dependency to the lombok project?

Answer (score 3):

1. download jar

   ```
   curl -# -O https://projectlombok.org/downloads/lombok.jar
   ```
2. Paste the jar where `eclipse.ini` present. In most of the case it'll
   be inside

   ```
   Eclipse.app > Contents > Eclipse
   ```
3. Execute the command to setup eclipse

   ```
   java -jar lombok.jar
   ```
4. Restart eclipse

Also, dont forget to add the Lombok dependency to your application

For Gradle Project,

```
compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
```

For Maven,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did it exacly like that but it still does not work. Is there anything else what I might missing?

Comment: Gradle or Maven, what do you use?

Comment: I am using Maven

Comment: Try cleaning Eclipse using `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` inside your application

Comment: Ok, this shows me a problem. There is somethimg wrong with Maven: Please verify your invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Comment: Ive added it to my last comment

Comment: What does `mvn install` produce?

Comment: mvn install does not work : Can't be find or is written wrong

Comment: This is the npm-debug file after I tryed doing mvn install:

Comment: I don't think Lombok is the issue here. Your app is not running properly. If you can run it, the Lombok will work fine

Comment: @DanielDalan you can accept the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 2):

There's very little context to work from here but from what I can see, these errors suggest that the Lombok library is not in you compile-time class path(as resolved by Eclipse).

If you are using Maven as your build tool, try and do a build from the terminal (outside Eclipse). If that builds well, then maybe Eclipse has not refreshed your Maven dependencies. You would have to verify that by looking into the Maven Dependecies library (Eclipse library that is) to see if your Lombok dependency is showing there.

Also check if Eclipse has Annotation Processing is enabled, go to Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing

It's a shot in the dark so I hope it helps